# Units for volume and density

Tags: si-units

I am a bit confused with using the appropriate units. I have two values for density and volume which contain units of:

Density $\rho$ = kg m^-3

Volume v = m^3

One thing i am confused here is why density is per meters negative cubed and volume is per meters positive cubed?

What is the difference between the two ? I am trying to visualize this in my mind in a physical aspect to understand why this is the case but don't fully understand it.

Comment: Units for volume are not kg m$^3$, just m$^3$. The reason for the negative sign is that density is inversely related to volume.

Comment: Oops sorry that was a typo for volume.

Comment: @HDE226868 wikipedia states: Density is kg/m3 which is a postive cubed..

Comment: I expanded that into an answer, addressing your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't necessarily make conceptual sense to use units of m<sup>-3</sup>. After all, can you picture one meter<sup>-1</sup>? Not easily.

The units of density you give there are kg$\cdot$m<sup>-3</sup>. This is equivalent to a different formulation: kg/m<sup>3</sup>. We now have a positive exponent, because we're treating the total units as a fraction: kilograms over cubic meters.

This leads to a better conceptual interpretation. If our density is $x$ kg/m<sup>3</sup>, then in every m<sup>3</sup> - a cubic meter - there are $x$ kilograms of matter.

The way to read negative exponents in units is "something" per "something", which makes more sense conceptually (I hope!).

Comment: So how would a positive exponent be read if negatives mean `per something` ?

Comment: @WDUK Just read it normally - say "kilograms".